# Find divs with a unique class and id using html-agility-pack

Tags: c#, vb.net, html-agility-pack

How do I get all divs that have a **class = 'round'** and a **id = 'footer'** in the htmlagilitypack?

I thought I could do th below but it does not work?

```
Dim s As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class ='round' and @id='footer']")
```

Comment: your code should work. What exactly have you done with `s` after this line? Are you sure, your `htmlDoc`is in the desired state?

Comment: Same here.  Looks good to me.  Could you show a sample html document that fails with this XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath looks right to me, I would double check the HTML to be sure it includes such element.